# Python/MySQL: "Truncated incorrect double value..." on a simple text insert

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python, pymysql

I've got a problem with a presumably simple text insert into a MySQL database from Python. The text is a HTML string, with which I want to update an existing row based on this rows primary key. I'm using this statement with PyMySQL (line breaks added for readability):

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE my_table SET my_text_col = %s
    AND another_int_col = %s WHERE my_table_pk_col = %s",
    (some_html_string, some_int, this_rows_pk))
```

This should be fairly straightforward, but (as way to often with MySQL) it apparently isn't. I get

```
Warning: (1292, Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: [Beginning of some_html_string])
```

and the `my_text_col` is set to `0`.

I have no idea why this doesn't work. There is no double field in this table, the HTML is a string that gets properly escaped, the other two values are ints. I have seen that others reported similar issues, and there are even bug reports related to this ([#43437](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=43437), [#46641](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=46641)), but these are more than 8 years old and haven't been fixed (I'm using MySQL 5.6.27 and PyMySQL 0.7.11).

If anyone has solution or a workaround to get this simple update done I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a simple but not obvious syntax error:

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
    SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]
```

This is the syntax from the docs (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html), multiple fields are seperated with commas not with AND in update statements.

Comment: My god. So I have wasted two hours because MySQL couldn't tell me that it expected a comma instead of an and, or *at least* just throw me a syntax error? And instead send me into a completely wrong direction?? What an utter crap. Anyway, thank you!